# How i can use grep to match a string in a file and the then write a message for each line in another file?

Tags: bash, grep

For example in input file I have:

- test
- test
- not
- not
- test

An in the output file i want to write:

- ok
- ok
- error
- error
- ok

Comment: i've tried somthing like this: cat input.txt | grep test | echo "ok" >> output.txt

Comment: but i don't now why it write just once in the output file and how to write the error message.

Comment: and this is just an example of input file in the real one i have to use regular expressions, and its recommended to use grep.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `grep` use `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/test/ok/' -e 's/not/error/' file
```

Comment: @CosteaGabriel but why?

Comment: well the real input file contains ip addresses and in the problem recommends me to use grep.

Comment: in that case don't show us another input file format. It's misleading.